# I am having trouble overlaying graphics on another window

Tags: c#, .net, graphics, overlay

Program.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Test {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++) {
                WindowHandler.testOverlay();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

WindowHandler.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Test {
    static class WindowHandler {
        private const String WINDOW_TITLE = "Minesweeper";
        private static IntPtr windowHandle = IntPtr.Zero;

        public static void testOverlay() {
            if (windowHandle == IntPtr.Zero) {
                windowHandle = getWindowHandle();
            }

            Graphics g = Graphics.FromHwnd(windowHandle);
            g.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.White), 0, 0, 10000, 10000);
        }

        private static IntPtr getWindowHandle() {
            foreach (Process proc in Process.GetProcesses()) {
                if (proc.MainWindowTitle == WINDOW_TITLE) {
                    return proc.MainWindowHandle;
                }
            }

            MessageBox.Show("Error: Unable to find window.");
            return IntPtr.Zero;
        }
    }
}
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I am writing a Minesweeper Solver and I am trying to overlay graphics on the Minesweeper window to provide debugging information. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work at all as I do not see any change on my screen. I am looping 1000000000 times in Program.cs just in case it erases my overlay on every frame refresh. I prefer to not try to hook DirectX.

Comment: I'm guessing the Windows Forms control overrides your overlay :)... Try overriding the OnPaint event on the Form class and put your own graphics behind the base.Paint(...)

Comment: Oh, Minesweeper uses WinForms? I didn't know that.

Comment: I ended up doing

    `Graphics g = Graphics.FromHwnd(IntPtr.Zero);`

and that seemed to work.

Comment: Ok it seems initializing Graphics with IntPtr.Zero acquires the desktop graphics context... Well i didn't know you use the native Minesweeper application by windows...